# Can I embed helpers with PyroCMS?

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

```
  {{ blog:posts limit="1" order-by="created_on" order-dir="desc" category="nurse" }}
    <p>
      {{ helper:word_limiter limit="10" string={{ helper:strip_tags value=body }} }}
    </p>
  {{ /blog:posts }}
```

Doesn't seem to work. Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried it with quotes?: `{{ helper:word_limiter limit="10" string="{{ helper:strip_tags value="body" }}" }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to send a tag with attributes to another attribute it actually looks like this:

```
{{ blog:posts limit="1" order-by="created_on" order-dir="desc" category="nurse" }}
<p>
  {{ helper:word_limiter limit="10" string={ helper:strip_tags value=body } }}
</p>
{{ /blog:posts }}
```

Double brackets say "I am starting Lex now".
Single brackets say "I am grouping these attributes to this call".

Comment: I get a PHP error:

`
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: preg_match(): Compilation failed: numbers out of order in {} quantifier at offset 21

Filename: helpers/text_helper.php

Line Number: 62
`